# User Look up field on Contact object

Tags: user-management, userlicense

I have a User lookup files on Contact object for reporting purpose. But I can't see 'Customer Community login users' through that lookup field. But I can see Salesforce and platform license users. There is no filter setup on the lookup field. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Which experience are you in - classic or LEX? Also are you doing an inline edit or by clicking on edit button?

Comment: Classic experience and inline edit

Comment: Okay, so try a full edit (by clicking the edit button), you should be able to see a dropdown to be able to select the "user type".

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you provided:

> Classic experience and inline edit

The user type selection looks like not to be available in inline edit in classic. However if you click on the edit button, you will be able to select the type of the user as well. Refer to the image below.

[image]